# FTP Server Connection Process using File Zilla Server

Tags: ftp

I need to know about ftp server connection using File Zilla Server.I want to transfer files from client machine to server and later i want to download it from server.I have installed ftp server in my windows machine and i did settings like username,password,location directory.Then ftp server got connected,then after a moment or sometime ftp server is disconnected.
I cant able to change settings while it is in disconnecting stage.if i need connection back then i need to reinstall File Zilla Server and make necessary changes in settings ,then it will get connect again. Often i cant do this reinstallation.Please help me step by step process to setup file Zilla Server and how to connect server through the client machine using ip address

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).